# Why worksheet Id changing after reopening document (Excel javascript API )?

Tags: javascript, excel, ms-office, worksheet, office-js

In my Excel tab-pane addin after adding worksheet(manually/programmatically) and running code below I have worksheet object where id is "{040E0F18-0F61-4CD9-886D-95112C925793}", then I save workbook, close and open again, run code below and it shows me that the worksheet.id now is "{00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000}"! 
In office.js [reference](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/worksheet.md) about worksheet id:

> The value of the identifier remains the same even when the
>   worksheet is renamed or moved. Read-only.

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().load('name');
          return ctx.sync().then(function () {  
                console.log(sheet);
          });
  });
```

Comment: That should not be happening...  What Office version/platform are you using?

Comment: Excel from Office 2016, Office.js api version 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheet) was ([very](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/commit/66497a02cc485e57c1a68ac025a010711ed8c4fd)) recently updated to clarify this. The ID shouldn't change within the same session (i.e. while the document is open). They do however change between sessions (i.e. when a document is opened and closed).

From the latest documentation:

> Returns a value that uniquely identifies the worksheet in a given
>   workbook. The value of the identifier remains the same even when the
>   worksheet is renamed or moved. Values change with each session of the
>   file being opened. Read-only.

Comment: That makes no sense, what if I need to store some sheet-specific metadata in the document metadata. How do I identify the sheet?

Comment: At the moment there isn't a good answer for sheet-specific data. The settings object is scoped to the Workbook. An immutable identifier is being looked into but there isn't an ETA that I'm aware of.